# Bit as eighth of dollar vs Shannon's Binary Digit?

Tags: computers, information-theory

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit#History does not mention the common usage of bit being  an eighth of a dollar -- surely Shannon was inspired by this?

This question was asked in 2019 in English stackexchange: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/510544/is-there-any-connection-between-1-bit-1-8-dollar-and-1-bit-1-8-byte

Comment: Best I can tell, the contemporary record does not support this hypothesis. Example: Robert M. Fano, "The Transmission of Information", Technical Report No. 65, MIT Research Laboratory of Electronics, March 17, 1949: " *We shall adopt for this unit the convenient name of "bit" (from "binary digit"), suggested by Shannon* ". In the report Fano thanks "Dr. Wiener and Dr. Shannon" for discussions and early access to their manuscripts, so clearly he was one of those in the know.

Comment: Paul J. Nahin, "The Logician and the Engineer", Princeton University Press 2013, p. 115: "... with Shannon crediting its coining to the mathematician (at Bell Labs and then later at Princeton University) John W. Tukey (1915-2000). It's a contraction of "**b**inary dig**it**",  ..."

Comment: Warren Weaver, "Recent Contributions to the Mathematical Theory of Communication", 1949 ([scan](https://pure.mpg.de/rest/items/item_2383164/component/file_2383163/content)): " *This unit of information is called a "bit," this word, first suggested by John W. Tukey, being a condensation of "binary digit"* ".

Comment: Claude E. Shannon, "The Mathematical Theory of Communication", *The Bell System Technical Journal*, Vol. 27, No. 3, July 1948, pp. 379-423: "If the base 2 is used the resulting units may be called binary digits, or more briefly *bits*, a word suggested by J. W. Tukey."

Comment: https://www.theguardian.com/news/2000/aug/16/guardianobituaries1
The American John Tukey, who has died aged 85, was among the most inventive pure and applied mathematicians of the last 50 years. [...] In 1944, Tukey coined the term "bit," an abbreviation of "binary digit", to describe the 1s and 0s that are the basis of the binary code in which all digital computer programs are produced. He was also credited with conceiving the word "software".

Comment: I agree.  There is no relation between these two words "bit".

Comment: Bit as in "2 bits" in the good old days when a quarter might buy a burger and fries (as late as 1960s) was a very common term and your statement implying no relationship twixt the monetary and compsci usage is much too strong.

Comment: @njuffa: I see your point but I can tell you that when I heard the word "bit" in the computer context I thought of bit in the monetary/2 bit sense instantly as any American old enough would have. The 1/8 thing is not the only idea: the division of a unit into subunits (as the dollar/doubloon was) irrespective how many is key. If u are not old enough to remember buying stuff for "2 bits" maybe that is why u are having trouble with the obvious.

Comment: @njuffa: did u read the link?